# New users on Django app at heroku doesn't persist on database

Tags: python, mysql, django, heroku

We started a project on Heroku, using Django, but users aren't persisted on Django User table on our database, but as Admin users at Django?

We use User.objects.create_user() from django.contrib.auth.models.User

Database is MySQL

Any tips?

### **Update 1 (2023-04-04)**

Some code snippets

*views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

...code...

def insertUser(request):

...code...

        # Username validation
        if User.objects.filter(username=request.POST['name']).exists():
            data['msg'] = 'Usuário já cadastrado!'
            data['class'] = 'alert-danger'
            return render(request, 'cadUser.html', data)
        # Email validation
        if User.objects.filter(email=request.POST['email']).exists():
            data['msg'] = 'Email já cadastrado!'
            data['class'] = 'alert-danger'
            return render(request, 'cadUser.html', data)
        # Validação de Registro funcional

        # New user recording
        user = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['name'], request.POST['email'], request.POST['password'])
        Docente.reg_funcional = request.POST['reg_funcional']
        #user.reg_funcional = request.POST['reg_funcional']
        user.save()
        data['msg'] = 'Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!'
        data['class'] = 'alert-success'
        return render(request, 'loginUser.html', data)
```

*settings.py*

```
 from pathlib import Path
 import django_on_heroku

 ...settings...

 INSTALLED_APPS = [
     <our stuff>,
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'django_simple_cookie_consent',
 ]
 
 ...settings...

 DATABASES = {
     'default': { 
         'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
         <connection stuff>
     }
 }
 
 AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
     {
         'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
     },
     {
         'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
     },
     {
         'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
     },
     {
         'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
     },
 ]

 ...settings...

 django_on_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Comment: We setted MySQL at setting.py with all the credentials

Comment: How did you do that? Are you _sure_ that it's working? You see data going into the MySQL database when you save records?

Comment: What does "users aren't persisted on Django User table on our database, but as Admin users at Django?" mean?

Comment: We created the user, but instead to be on django.user table at our, it is only be shown on heroku user database at heroku, but not at on the databes

Comment: I still don't understand. Please read [ask], then come back and [edit] your question to be as clear as possible. You'll probably want to show the relevant Python code.

Comment: Now it's updated

Comment: Thank you for updating. Now, please try to explain "instead to be on django.user table at our, it is only be shown on heroku user database at heroku, but not at on the databes" as clearly as possible. What do you mean by "django.user table at our" and "heroku user database at heroku" and "not at on the databes"?

Comment: When we connect directly at the database, table `django.users` is  totally clean. However, when get inside Django's admin tool, any user shows there, even not persisted on the database. The problem is: they are persisted, but we don't know where... :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using [`django-on-heroku`](https://github.com/pkrefta/django-on-heroku).

One of the things this library does out of the box is to override your datbabase connection parameters with whatever is in your `DATABASE_URL` environment variable. It is very likely that the MySQL parameters that you have set manually are not being used.

You can [disable features](https://github.com/pkrefta/django-on-heroku#disabling-functionality) by passing keyword arguments to `django_on_heroku.settings()`, e.g.:

```py
django_on_heroku.settings(locals(), databases=False)
```

That should prevent `django_on_heroku` from modifying your `settings.DATABASES`.

I suggest you also review the config vars and addons that you have set. If you're paying for Heroku Postgres, or some other database addon that you don't need, you'll probably want to remove it.